# Parentheses inside link text in markdown

Tags: markdown

I need to get links with parentheses in the text (these links are academic citations in a website, and the link takes the user to the full citation). However, I am unable to get this to function using Markdown, as the parentheses get deleted. Here is the code I am using:

```
[Author (year)](../path/to/source)
```

What I get when this is rendered is the following, with the parentheses removed:

> Author year

But what I want is:

> Author (year)

I have tried using HTML escape sequences for the parentheses, i.e.
`&#40; &#41;`, but this has not worked either. How can I get the parentheses inside my link to stay there when rendered into HTML?

Comment: What Markdown implementation are you using? In my [testing](https://babelmark.github.io/?text=%5BAuthor+(year)%5D(..%2Fpath%2Fto%2Fsource)), it works fine in any implementation that I am aware of.

Comment: Good question. I am using clld-markdown-plugin (https://github.com/clld/clld-markdown-plugin) -- perhaps I should contact the maintainer of this repository.

Comment: It appears that that project wraps Python-Markdown. As it turns out, I am the primary maintainer of Python-Markdown and your syntax works fine in Python-Markdown directly. So, yes, you may want to contact the maintainer of that project.